SMILES notation includes vertical bar | and lp Sg
I came across a SMILES notation I don't know in the DSSTox database. Here's an example:
OS(=O)(=O)CCCNCCNC(=O)C(F)(F)F |lp:0:2,2:2,3:2,7:1,10:1,12:2,14:3,15:3,16:3,Sg:n:13,15,14:4-8:ht|
The beginning is as I would expect, but it is followed by a series of descriptors between vertical bars $\vert$.
The SMILES is parsed without errors in Rdkit, but the part between vertical bars is left out when re-exporting to SMILES (or Inchi).
Does anyone know what the part between vertical bars means, and when/why it is used?

The notation you found is a CXSMILES and you can depict it with CDKDepict (using the Chemistry Development Kit):

We started exploring it for compound classes for lipids and Wikidata, see this write up.
The lp is for lone pair, and the Sg is for S-group, which can be used for repeated units.

Thanks, that's very helpful. I see Rdkit has also documentation on its CXSMILES extension.
